# QList to QQmlListProperty

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to pass QList into QML using QQmlListProperty, as official documentation says:

```
QQmlListProperty::QQmlListProperty(QObject *object, void *data, CountFunction count, AtFunction at)
```

My code is:

```
QQmlListProperty<TTimingDriver> TTiming::getDrivers()
{
    return QQmlListProperty<TTimingDriver>(this, &m_drivers, &TTiming::count, &TTiming::driverAt);
}

int TTiming::count(QQmlListProperty<TTimingDriver> *property)
{
    TTiming * timing = qobject_cast<TTiming *>(property->object);
    return timing->m_drivers.count();
}

TTimingDriver * TTiming::driverAt(QQmlListProperty<TTimingDriver> *property, int i)
{
    TTiming * timing = qobject_cast<TTiming *>(property->object);
    return timing->m_drivers.at(i);
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
no matching function for call to 'QQmlListProperty<TTimingDriver>::QQmlListProperty(TTiming*, QList<TTimingDriver*>*, int (TTiming::*)(QQmlListProperty<TTimingDriver>*), TTimingDriver* (TTiming::*)(QQmlListProperty<TTimingDriver>*, int))'
 return QQmlListProperty<TTimingDriver>(this, &m_drivers, &TTiming::count, &TTiming::driverAt);
```

Comment: Are `TTiming::count()` and `TTiming::driverAt` declared static?

Comment: @jpnurmi no, are they have to?

Comment: @jpnurmi thank you, this is it!

Answer (score 2):

I think <ou are mixing two of the QQmlListProperty constructor overloads.

The one that takes the QList<T*> does not need pointers to functions.

So this should be sufficient

```
QQmlListProperty<TTimingDriver> TTiming::getDrivers()
{
    return QQmlListProperty<TTimingDriver>(this, &m_drivers);
}
```

Assuming that m_drivers is of type `QList<TTimingDriver*>`

Comment: As official documentation says, "Generally this constructor should not be used in production code, as a writable QList violates QML's memory management rules. However, this constructor can be very useful while prototyping". http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html#QQmlListProperty

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the implementation of the callbacks used by that constructor overload, e.g. https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/qml/qml/qqmllist.h.html#_ZN16QQmlListProperty12qlist_appendEP16QQmlListPropertyIT_EPS1_ then this is very close to what you would implement yourself.
I.e. you would probably cast the object to your class and then access m_drivers.append() in the append function. So the only difference would be that you could do that cast as a checked cast, e.g. using qobject_cast or dynamic_cast, but the list access would very likely be the same

Comment: In my experience, as long as you don't have references to objects that might get removed later on, you are fine. That means no ids, and if you expose such objects as properties, make sure to null those when the objects get removed. It is a rather important clarification.

Comment: I think `m_drivers` should be `&m_drivers`.

Comment: Note: Older versions of Qt expect a reference instead of a pointer